# Check if all IQueryable items are inequal to default<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have these lines of code getting the session of a given user, deleting the session and then deleting the user.

```
var row = _dbContext.User.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == id);
if (row != null)
    {
        var session = _dbContext.Session.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserId == id);
        if (session != default(Session))
            dbContext.Remove(session);

        _dbContext.Remove(row);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now we found that, for some reason, there can be multiple sessions on one user. So we wish to delete all sessions found, before deleting the user. Therefore I have refactored the `var session` line...

```
var session = _dbContext.Session.Where(s => s.UserId == id);
```

..which now returns an `IQueryable<Session>`. But how do I validate this collection the same way as before? But now checking if all items of the IQueryable are inequal to `default(Session)`. Can I do the following?..

```
if (session != default(IQueryable<Session>))
    _dbContext.RemoveRange(session);
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: Didn't you configure cascaded delete?

Comment: the default of any class is null

Comment: @GertArnold Cascaded delete is enabled by default. But for some reason it doesn't work. This project contains a lot of legacy code so something might not be configured right somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
// .ToList will perform a query to your DB
var sessions = dbContext.Session.Where(s => s.UserId == id).ToList();
if (sessions.Count() != 0) {
    // IMO the "check" isnt necessary anymore, unless you perform some operation on the else case
    dbContext.RemoveRange(sessions);
}
dbContext.Remove(user);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In the case that your `User` entity model has a correctly configured navigation property that associates a user to its related sessions, you could do:

```
user.Sessions.Clear();
dbContext.Remove(user);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I choose to go with this answer. Doing `sessions.Count() != 0` works. User has a navigation property that points to Session, but im going with the first solution. Thank you @Jota.Toledo

Answer (score 0):

While `_dbContext.Session.Where(s => s.UserId == id)` returns an instance that contains 0 sessions, `default(IQueryable<Session>)` is null. Collection based lambda expressions does not return null in linq